# Python turn a list of numbers into a Counter of ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping

Given a `list` of numbers (`int`s or `float`s, usually `float`s), and a number `step`, what is the best way to turn the `list` into a `Counter`, so that the keys are two-element `tuple`s, each a multiple of `step`, and the values are the counts of numbers that fall into the range greater than the first number and less than the second number for the respective key?

I have written a minimal reproducible example, to illustrate what I intend to achieve. I already found a solution, but I don't think it is the most efficient way.

```py
import random
from bisect import bisect
from collections import Counter

def get_sample(n=256, high=20):
    return [random.random()*high for _ in range(n)]

sample = get_sample()

def analyze_sample(sample, step):
    ceiling = round(max(sample) / step) + 1
    steps = [i*step for i in range(ceiling)]
    bands = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(steps, steps[1:])]
    result = Counter()
    for n in sample:
        result[bands[bisect(steps, n)-1]] += 1
    
    return Counter({k: v for k, v in sorted(result.items())})

analyze_sample(sample, 0.5)
```

What is a better way?

---

### Update

I just turned my code into a linear search, it is much faster, but still slow.

```
def linear_analyze_sample(sample, step):
    sample = sorted(sample)
    ceiling = round(sample[-1] / step) + 1
    steps = [i*step for i in range(ceiling)]
    bands = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(steps, steps[1:])]
    result = dict()
    i = 0
    it = iter(sample)
    n = next(it)
    for step in steps[1:]:
        count = 0
        if n == 1e309:
            break
        while n <= step:
            count += 1
            n = next(it, 1e309)
        result[bands[i]] = count
        i += 1
    
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(result.items())}
```

```
In [120]: linear_analyze_sample(sample, 0.5) == analyze_sample(sample, 0.5)
Out[120]: True

In [121]: %timeit analyze_sample(sample, 0.5)
179 µs ± 2.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [122]: %timeit linear_analyze_sample(sample, 0.5)
62.5 µs ± 380 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: If you're lazy or want performance, why not use Pandas for the binning? https://www.statology.org/data-binning-in-python/

Comment: You can use the numpy library to leverage vectorized operations and simplify the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the ranges directly using the floor of the division by step to get a chunk number, and multiplying it back by step to get the range start and stop values:

```
result = Counter( (step*int(n/step),step*int(n/step)+step) for n in sample)
```

In order to minimize the number of redundant computations, you may want to build the counter with chunk numbers first, and convert them to ranges at the end:

```
chunks = Counter( int(n/step) for n in sample)
result = { (k*step,(k+1)*step):c for k,c in chunks.items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def new_analyze_sample(sample, step):
    ceiling = round(max(sample) / step) + 1
    steps = [i*step for i in range(ceiling)]
    bands = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(steps, steps[1:])]
    result = Counter()
    for n in sample:
        result[bands[int(n // step)]] += 1

    return Counter({k: v for k, v in sorted(result.items())})
```

This approach is more efficient because it avoids the use of the `bisect()` function. The `bisect()` function is a binary search algorithm that is used to find the insertion point for a given value in a sorted list. In this case, we are not actually interested in the insertion point, so we can avoid using the `bisect()` function and save some time.